# SQLite3::SQLException: no such table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

[Server log screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bysEU.jpg)

Hi everyone!
Was writing a rating system for an airBnb style project so i made the objects Host and Guest as reference to the User object.
But something is wrong in my code:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.hosts
```

In fact the method looks for host table i dont have cause it should be associated to the Users one.

migration

```
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
      t.text :comment
      t.integer :star, default: 1
      t.references :car, foreign_key: true
      t.references :reservation, foreign_key: true
      t.references :guest, foreign_key: true
      t.references :host, foreign_key: true
      t.string :type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "comment"
    t.integer "star", default: 1
    t.integer "car_id"
    t.integer "reservation_id"
    t.integer "guest_id"
    t.integer "host_id"
    t.string "type"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["car_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_car_id"
    t.index ["guest_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_guest_id"
    t.index ["host_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_host_id"
    t.index ["reservation_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_reservation_id"
```

Models:

```
class HostReview < Review
  belongs_to :host, class_name: "User"
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
....
  has_many :host_reviews, class_name: "HostReview", foreign_key: "host_id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
t.references :host, references: :users, foreign_key: true
```

or alternatively

```
t.integer :host_id
```

and then

```
add_foreign_key :reviews, :users, column: :host_id
```